# chrome extension to read the content of gmail attachment (pdf)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension, would like to know how to read the attachment programmatically, have searched in SO and in Google.

Does anybody know how I can do this? thanks in advance

Comment: This doesn't completely answer your question, but I did find a [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047053/). Just thought it might help.

Comment: @Jacque Thanks a lot for taking time to help me, I have seen that post already, but I couldn't find idea or suggestion for doing it programmatically from that post.